# How to clear a cache of Web site in server

Tags: cache, google-compute-engine, web-hosting

I developed a website. It has been hosted in google cloud platform.I was required to change the banner of picture of the home page of website. I changed in server but It showed previous banner picture so I cleared the cache by following command

```
sudo touch /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush
```

Subsequently I refresh the web page then the picture was changed as new picture. But after few hours or when i click another page and again come to this page  The previous(old) picture again replaced the new picture. What can I do to solve this problem and what is the reason?

Comment: are you using a loadbalancer in front or you are serving directly with a webserver?

Comment: which webserver, have you switch your browser to see if your browser is not serving you cache?

Comment: I am using Google cloud platform

Comment: can you please provide more information on the platform-
- server type n version, webserver, app?

Comment: remind to flzsh the Browser cache also

Answer (score 0):

> I cleared the cache by following command
>
> `sudo touch /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush`

Are you sure your banner is cached in `/var/cache/mod_pagespeed` ?

---

Based on Linux Foundation documentation [[1]](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s05.html), the cached files can be deleted without data loss.

At this point, just;

```
rm -rf /var/cache/*
```